# Their goal "was inspiring/was to" and educating future generations. - Which one is correct?

Tags: usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

**Example 1**

> (1) Their aim **was to enhance** personal well-being and promote healthy lifestyles.

> (2) Their aim **was enhancing** personal well-being and promoting healthy lifestyles.

**Example 2**

> (1) Their goal **was to inspire** and educate future generations. However, they have a different goal now.

> (2) Their goal **was inspiring** and educating future generations. However, they have a different goal now.

Which one is correct?
I don't see (2) that often. Are there some constraints in terms of this kind of structure?

Comment: In both cases (2) is potentially ambiguous (the goal was itself an inspiration to people?).